# Parsing a string of 'single quotes' as json in presto

Tags: sql, casting, presto, single-quotes

~I want to cast a string of 'single quotes' string like below code.~

---

Sorry, I changed the question.
i replace the 'single quotes' to "double quotes"

Example

```sql
WITH data as (
    SELECT 
        '{"svod": True, "awards": [], "copyright": "© ROI VISUAL / EBS All rights Reserved.", "providerId": "50176b59-9bae-40ed-bedd-167786953c73", "releaseYear": 2018, "rating_levels": {"drugs": "none", "theme": "none", "horror": "none", "language": "none", "violence": "none", "sex_and_nudity": "none", "imitable_behavior": "none"}, "display_runtime": "00:05:00", "production_company": "ROIVISUAL"}' as meta
)

SELECT 
    -- json_parse(meta) -- X (Error : Cannot convert value to JSON)
    cast(meta as json) as meta_json, -- O > "{\"svod\": True, \"awards\": [], \"copyright\": \"© ROI VISUAL / EBS All rights Reserved.\", \"providerId\": \"50176b59-9bae-40ed-bedd-167786953c73\", \"releaseYear\": 2018, \"rating_levels\": {\"drugs\": \"none\", \"theme\": \"none\", \"horror\": \"none\", \"language\": \"none\", \"violence\": \"none\", \"sex_and_nudity\": \"none\", \"imitable_behavior\": \"none\"}, \"display_runtime\": \"00:05:00\", \"production_company\": \"ROIVISUAL\"}"
    json_extract_scalar(cast(meta as json), '$.providerId') as meta_providerId -- Empty Return
FROM data
```

Expected Results

```sql
SELECT 
 json_extract_scalar(cast(meta as json), '$.releaseYear'), -- 2018
 json_extract_scalar(cast(meta as json), '$.providerId') -- "50176b59-9bae-40ed-bedd-167786953c73"
FROM data
```

I've referred to this before, but it didn't work out.

- [How to cast varchar to MAP(VARCHAR,VARCHAR) in presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55279784/how-to-cast-varchar-to-mapvarchar-varchar-in-presto)
- [How to extract keys in a nested json array object in Presto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478518/how-to-extract-keys-in-a-nested-json-array-object-in-presto)
- [Presto Build JSON Array with Different Data Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72040483/presto-build-json-array-with-different-data-types)

Do you have any advice for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use the `json_extract`-function in your insert? https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html?highlight=json#json-functions

Comment: @Natrium Yeah, but It doesn't convert to json fisrt.

Comment: It does not convert TO json, it converts FROM json. That's how I understood your question: I have a json and I want to insert values from that json into my database.

Comment: @Natrium Sorry for confusing. I changed the Question.

Comment: Could you try it without casting to json? According to the docs, it should be able to work a string/varchar without casting.

Comment: I tried many times without casting to json. but, it not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON appears to be invalid.

Use either `"True"` (with quotes) or `true` (without quotes, lowercase) to make your JSON valid.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's why it didn't work. Thanks @Natrium

Comment: So, i finally solve this problem by Regular Expression 
like this
`regexp_extract(replace(meta, '''', '"'), '(?<="releaseYear": )[0-9]{4}') AS releaseYear`

Comment: @이인영 well done!